# How to use tools such as buttons under a nsview in swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, wkwebview, nsview

I removed default window's titlebar, and then added two `WKWebView` in the window. I add a `NSView` on the main `wkwebview` to make the window draggable, but I can't use those html element such as textfield,button and so on which are under the `NSView` area.I have made `NSView` transparent,but it's just backgroundcolor transparent not mouse click transparent. So there is a solution available?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use hit testing technique https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/1483364-hittest

I've created an [example project on GitHub](https://github.com/alex-shapkin/hittest.example)

Comment: thanks so much ,but I can't run your project because of a signing error: Code Signing Error: Signing for "mouse_events" requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor. I just start learning swift several days ago and never use OC before.I'm so sorry.

Comment: I've just deleted code sign requirements so you can try it again.

Comment: Thanks,It can work now, but html element such as button in the customWebView can't still be used although the customWebView can receive mouse event. WKWebView doesn't seem to have hittest function.

Comment: Could you provide an example, please?

Comment: I forked and modified your example project, you can try it from [here](https://github.com/zhaowweny/hittest.example/tree/master/mouse_events.test)